# How to load a pickle object and resolve certain references

Tags: python, pickle

Say we have an object we write to binary file using `pickle`. Let's say the object graph looks like this:

```
foo1
 +--->bar
 |     \--->context
 +--->baz
 |     +--->context
 |     \--->qux
 \--->context
```

Now the `context` objects are large datastructures and all instances of qux are the same. Therefore we decided to leave these `contexxt` objects out of the pickle process with:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    my_dict = dict(self.__dict__)
    my_dict['context'] = None  # We don't save the context
    return my_dict
```

for the classes to which `foo`, `bar` and `baz` belong (and in fact all other classes in our design).

When we `load()` the object back into memory, we want all `context` references to be set back to our given context. One can do this by walking over the object tree recursively, but we are wondering whether there is a more elegant solution in `pickle` that fills in the `context` values itself when loading the data back into memory?

Comment: Are you looking for [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) or am I missing something?

Comment: @IljaEverilä: the problem is that `__setstate__` has no additional parameters such that we can set the context back. Nevertheless I think I've found an answer in *persistent pickling* (https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pickle.html#pickle-persistent).

Comment: Nice, did not know of that (reference to outside object support). Your own finding seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.context` is of type `Context`, instead of setting `context` to `None`, you could adapt the code from the section [Persistence of External Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#persistence-of-external-objects) in the `pickle` documentation:

```
import pickle

class ContextAwarePickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        # if this is a context, return the key
        if isinstance(obj, Context):
            return ("Context", context.key)

        # pickle as usual
        return None


class ContextAwareUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def recover_context(self, key_id):
        ...

    def persistent_load(self, pid):
        type_tag, key_id = pid
        if type_tag == "Context":
            return self.recover_context(key_id)
        else:
            raise pickle.UnpicklingError("unsupported persistent object")
```

Comment: Thank you. A few minutes after asking the question, I found the example. Nevertheless, the modified code makes it easier to understand. +1.