# Pickle data with a persistent_id to a binary object (dumps and loads)

Tags: python, pickle

A first question I asked was [*how to load a pickle object and resolve certain references*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026745/how-to-load-a-pickle-object-and-resolve-certain-references). A next problem I'm facing is that I cannot call [`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) or [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) objects to a binary object.

Below is an implementation of the `ContextAwarePickler` and the `ContextAwareUnpickler`. How can I use these to convert an object to and back from its binary representation? As far as I know this only works for files.

```
import pickle

class ContextAwarePickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        # if this is a context, return the key
        if isinstance(obj, Context):
            return ("Context", context.key)

        # pickle as usual
        return None


class ContextAwareUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def recover_context(self, key_id):
        ...

    def persistent_load(self, pid):
        type_tag, key_id = pid
        if type_tag == "Context":
            return self.recover_context(key_id)
        else:
            raise pickle.UnpicklingError("unsupported persistent object")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is similar to the one in `dill` (I'm the author) -- but not as robust.

https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/cccbea9b715e16b742288e1e5a21a687a4d4081b/dill/temp.py#L169   (code snipped reproduced below)

```
def loadIO(buffer, **kwds):
    """load an object that was stored with dill.temp.dumpIO

    buffer: buffer object

    >>> dumpfile = dill.temp.dumpIO([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>> dill.temp.loadIO(dumpfile)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    import dill as pickle
    if PY3:
        from io import BytesIO as StringIO
    else:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    value = getattr(buffer, 'getvalue', buffer) # value or buffer.getvalue
    if value != buffer: value = value() # buffer.getvalue()
    return pickle.load(StringIO(value))

def dumpIO(object, **kwds):
    """dill.dump of object to a buffer.
Loads with "dill.temp.loadIO".  Returns the buffer object.

    >>> dumpfile = dill.temp.dumpIO([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>> dill.temp.loadIO(dumpfile)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    import dill as pickle
    if PY3:
        from io import BytesIO as StringIO
    else:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    file = StringIO()
    pickle.dump(object, file)
    file.flush()
    return file
```

Note that you may want to be careful about things like to `flush` the buffer on `dump`, as `dill` does.

Comment: exucse me i got _pickle.UnpicklingError: unsupported persistent id encountered
 when trying to open a pickle file can you help please

Comment: @user5520049: you should either submit an issue at https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill, or create a new post on SO.

Comment: excuse me i hope to post a new one but when i create a new one it will duplicate and SO close off it ,,

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer:

```
class ContextawarePickling :

    @staticmethod
    def load_aware (input_file,context=None) :
        return ContextawareUnpickler(input_file).load()

    @staticmethod
    def dump_aware (object_to_save,output_file):
        ContextawarePickler(output_file).dump(object_to_save)

    @staticmethod
    def loads_aware (stream,context=None) :
        file = io.BytesIO(stream)
        return ContextawarePickling.load_aware(file)

    @staticmethod
    def dumps_aware (object_to_save):
        f = io.BytesIO()
        ContextawarePickling.dump_aware(object_to_save,f)
        return f.getvalue()
```

Basically you first create two utility methods: `load_aware` and `dump_aware`. Next one can implement `loads_aware` and `dumps_aware` where one wraps an `io.BytesIO` that acts as a handler to which and from which data can be loaded/stored.